# Estoy teniendo un conflicto en el while

Tags: php, while, bucle-for

Estoy teniendo un confito en mi `while` en donde yo tengo una tabla de categorías y la categoría `ej` tiene 10 categorías.

El problema surge al arrojar la id para revisar ya que me está arrojado el 2 en adelante:

```
<?php 
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database_conexion);
    $query_DatosCategorias = sprintf("SELECT * FROM categorias");
    $DatosCategorias= mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DatosCategorias) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_DatosCategorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosCategorias);
    $totalRows_DatosCategorias = mysqli_num_rows($DatosCategorias);

    $total = $totalRows_DatosCategorias;
    $limite = $total/2;
    $listas = null;
    $inicio = 1;
    $k = null;
    $listas = $total/$limite;
    $cantidadListas = ceil($listas);
    ?>
    <footer class="site-footer footer-light" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlWeb;?>/img/footer-bg-alt.png);">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <!-- categorias-->
                        <section class="widget widget-links">
                            <h3 class="widget-title">Categorias</h3>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <?php
                                        for ($i=$inicio; $i <=$cantidadListas; $i++) { 
                                            for ($j=1; $j <=$limite && $k<$total; $j++) { 
                                                $k = $k+1;
                                                $i=0;
                                                while ($row_DatosCategorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosCategorias)) {
                                                    $i++;
                                                    if ($i==1) {
                                                        echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";
                                                        echo "<ul>";
                                                    } // primera lista
                                                    echo '<li>'.$row_DatosCategorias['id'].'</li>';
                                                    if($i % $limite == 0 || $i == $total) { 
                                                        echo "</ul></div>"; // cerrar lista
                                                        // Si quedan más elementos abrir otra
                                                        if ($i < $total) {
                                                            echo "<ul>";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                } //end while
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
```

Comment: Prueba a poner el valor de `$inicio` en 0

Comment: si el unico incoveniente es en el while que aun estoy viedo como resolverlo enci pero es muy raro el error

Comment: Y para qué son exactamente esos dos bucles for?

Comment: @alex55132 esos bucles haces unos calculos para depediedo cuantos items hay asi los pone en un ul nuevo o no y tambien genera un <div> cada cierto numero especificado eso haria esto https://i.imgur.com/NPzys4F.jpg

Comment: Por que defines primero que la variable `$i = $inicio` cuando `$inicio = 1` pero luego dentro del for le asignas `$i=0` y, a su vez, dentro del while le añades uno? Por favor comenta el código para ver cuál es el funcionamiento lógico que esperas de él, es muy dificil leerlo asi

Comment: Yo empezaria arreglando el batiburrillo de variables que tienes y sobre todo simplificaria bastante el procedimiento porque lo has complicado bastante.